# Quanto scrolo o dataTable para cima ele sobe tudo de uma vez (Primefaces mobile)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estou usando Primefaces mobile e para apresentar alguns dados estou usando o dataTable, eu faço uma consulta e ele lista normalmente os registros, enquanto eu rolo os registros para baixo usando o navegador do meu celular ele desce normalmente.

O problema é que se depois de rolar os registros para baixo e depois rolar os registros para cima a tela sobe para o inicio dos registros ao invés de subir só um pouco,ou seja, se eu tiver 5000 registros, descer até o registro 2000 e depois rolar a tela para o registro 1900 só uma pouco para cima, para ver o registro para cima, ele rola para o topo da tela, para o primeiro registro, como evitar isso?

Para testar estou usando o celular